# Loop through all parameters passed to Twig template

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

Does anyone know how to loop through all parameters that are passed to a Twig template without knowing in advance what they are called?
The `{{ dump() }}` function (which calls `var_dump()`) outputs something like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["foo"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["bar"]=>
  string(3) "Yes"
  ["baz"]=>
  int(99)
  ["subdata1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo2"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["subdata2"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo3"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

I want to loop through all parameters which are not `subdata1` or `subdata2`, so that I can output something like:

```
foo is true
bar is Yes
baz is 99
```

Preserving the data structure sent to the template is important, so I am looking for a solution on the Twig side of the pipe.

For the past two days I have trawled through the sparse Twig documentation trying to find a hidden gem which reveals how to do this, but turned up nothing.

Comment: is there any reason you can't do this `before` the parameters are given to the template?  Twig uses the `output buffer` to provide nesting functionality, so naturally it makes no difference whether the parameters are manipulated before or after the rendering.

Comment: I don't understand this. I am new to Twig. Perhaps you could expand in a full answer?

Comment: Im just trying to get an idea of what you are trying to do first.  Are you using Symfony, or Twig on its own?

Comment: Twig on it's own. The extra tag is because I know Twig users are often Symphony users too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create your own function for this:

```
function get_other_context_vars($context)
{
    $vars = array();
    foreach ($context as $key => $value) {
        if (!$value instanceof Twig_Template && !in_array($key, array('subdata1', 'subdata2')) {
            $vars[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $vars;
}

$environment->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('get_other_context_vars', 'get_other_context_vars', array('needs_context' => true)));
```

Usage:

```
{% for name, var in get_other_context_vars() -%}
    {{ name }} is {{ var }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just inspect [how the `dump()` helper works](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php), then replicate similar behaviour in your custom extension.

Comment: This might have been a viable solution, but the using `$environment->addFunction()` is simpler, so I will go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if your value is an array

```
{% for value in values %}
    {% if value[0] is not defined %}
        {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This solution works if you can know the keys of yours subdatas.
The other solution is to create an other array in your controller using the is_array function to filter

Comment: I know the names of the properties `subdata1` and `subdata2`. They names of the other properties are dynamic and unknown.